# Faceted search with elasticsearch

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch, faceted-search

I'm trying to build a simple UI in Angular with facets on top of elasticsearch. Can someone point me to an example?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check the [ElasticUI](http://www.elasticui.com/) project, which provides AngularJS directives for Elasticsearch.

More specifically, that project provides support for single select facets with the `eui-singleselect` directive

```
<eui-singleselect field="YOUR_FIELD" size="5"></eui-singleselect>
```

...and multi-select facets with the `eui-checklist` directive

```
<eui-checklist field="YOUR_FIELD" size="10"></eui-checklist>
```

Check their [demo file](https://github.com/YousefED/ElasticUI/blob/master/examples/demo/demo.html) for sample usage.

Also see: [elasticui](/questions/tagged/elasticui)